# poor results with cats and dogs dataset .How to improve the accuracy

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

Hi I have a program whose task is to classify between images of cats and dogs. My algorithm does not learn and does not improve its accuracy. Any ideas on how to increase the accuracy in convolutional neural network(I dont know how to share jupyter file ).

Any general ways to improve the algorithm will help

Answer (score 1):

Well this question leaves a lot to the imagination, and therefore I can already assume that you tried to make a small neural network yourself. 
1) Did you use convolutional layers?
2) Did you try transfer learning? (InceptionV3, Vgg16, Xception,...)
3) Do you have enough data? 1000 images a class approximately

Maybe this site can be useful to understand certain things:
http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/

If I did not help you at all, then please rephrase your question :)